# Reverse jQuery effect after a given time

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

one quick question!

I am using the following code which does a "flip" card effect to flip a specific div element, when a certain link is mouse clicked. Is it possible to make the "flip" effect reverse after some time? Exactly as if I was clicking again with the mouse, but timed. I can do it now by cliking, but I would like to time it.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.flip_card').click(function () {
        var x = $(this).attr("id");
        var i = x.substring(10);
        $('.flip' + i + '').find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
    });
});
```

I have tried using the jquery functions delay() or settimeout, but I can only achieve that the first "flip" effect is delayed and happens after certain time. That is not what I want...

I hope my question is understanble enough.

Many thanks!

Comment: Maybe `setTimeout(function(){$('.flip_card').removeClass('flipped')})` ?

Comment: so after an interval all clicked flipcard will be removed?

Comment: Can include `html` at Question ?

Comment: @Akshay I have already tried that, but does not seem to work... And Begginer, yes, exactly!

Comment: @Beginner, you can see it easily here, its not a problem, but adding a functionality. :) http://qalbiol.coolpage.biz

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.flip_card').click(function () {
        var x = $(this).attr("id");
        var i = x.substring(10);
        var ele = '.flip' + i + '';
        $(ele).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
        setTimeout(function(){
            $(ele).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped');
        }, 1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: your answer is working flawlessly, many thanks! Always so quick at stackoverflow!!

Comment: Glad I could be of help :)

Answer (score 1):

Try utilizing `.queue()`

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(".flip_card").click(function () {
        var x = this.id;
        var i = x.substring(10);
        $(".flip" + i).find(".card").toggleClass("flipped")
        .queue("reset", function() {
          setTimeout(function() {
            $(".flip"+ i + " .card.flipped:eq(-1)").toggleClass("flipped");
             // set duration here
          }, 3000);
        }).dequeue("reset");
    });
});
```

Comment: I could not make it work like this, see answer above. Many thanks though!

Comment: @qalbiol Can include html from qalbiol.coolpage.biz at Question ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use `setTimeout()`, but you should keep track of the timer ID so you can cancel it if the user clicks again before the timeout has executed. You can use the `.data()` function to store the timer ID so each card keeps track of its own timer ID.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.flip_card').click(function () {
        var i = $(this).attr('id').substring(10);
        var $card = $('.flip' + i).find('.card');

        // Clear the timeout if there is one.
        var timerId = $card.data('timerId');
        if (timerId) {
            clearTimeout(timerId);
        }

        // Flip the card.
        if (!$card.hasClass('flipped')) {
            $card.addClass('flipped');

            // Set the timeout so the card is flipped back after 3 seconds.
            $card.data('timerId', setTimeout(function () {
                $card.removeClass('flipped');
            }, 3000));
        } else {
            $card.removeClass('flipped');
        }
    });
});
```

[jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5ftxLamr/1/)

Answer (score 0):

How about something this simple. Just chaining should make it.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.flip_card').bind('click', function() {
     var x = $(this).attr("id");
     var i = x.substring(10);
     var ele = '.flip' + i + '';
     $(ele).find('.card').toggleClass('flipped').delay(3000).toggleClass('flipped');
   });
});
```

Comment: sorry but this solution doesn't seem to be working. Thank you anyway.